# How to console log a word in a string?

Tags: javascript, string

I'm wondering how to console.log a word from a string based on the index.

```
let word = "Hello world";
console.log(word[0]) //log from index 0 to 4
```

How to log from index 0 to 4, because now i only know how to log a single letter.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
let word = "Hello world";
let wordArray = word.split(" ");
console.log(wordArray[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Split your string by your separator in your case space:

```
console.log(word.split(" ")[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `split` to get an array of the words and then use to index of the word position

```js
let sentence = "Hello world";
console.log(sentence.split(" ")[0]);
```

or if you know what word you are looking for you
can use `indexOf` together with the word length to slice it.

```js
    let sentence = "Hello world";
    console.log(sentence.slice(sentence.indexOf("Hello"), "Hello".length));
```

Answer (score 0):

Its ez mate,
first create function

```js
function clwobo(str){
  let a = str.split(" ")//Create an "a" variable to split "str" into an array
  return a[0]//This function will return the first word of the string, 1 will be 2 and so on
}
```

How to use this function?
Well

```js
clwobo("Hello world")
```

In console it will show

```
-- Console --
Hello
```

Try it first, then mark if its work.